# Replace uppercase letters between special pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I like to replace the letters "KELLY" bettween "#" with the same length of "#". (here, repetitive five #'s instead of 'KELLY')

```
$str = "####KELLY#####";   // any alpabet letters can come.
preg_replace('/(#{3,})[A-Z]+(#{3,})/', "$1$2", $str);
```

It returns `#########` (four hashes then five hashes) without 'KELLY'.

How can I get `##############` which is four original leading hashes, then replace each letter with a hash, then the five original trailing hashes?

Comment: `preg_replace_callback` + `str_repeat` + `str_len`

Comment: Adding `()` creates a capture group, you're getting the repetitive hashbangs `#` because those are what the regex captures, add the capture group to `[A-Z]` instead; here's a quick [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rBhLT7/1).

Comment: @Kim a "hashbang" is `#!`.  "hashtag" or "hash symbol" is `#`.

Comment: @user your exact desired output is not clearly defined in your question.  It would be better to explicitly display the exact desired text.

Comment: I want  Alpabet letter KELLY to be replace with hashtags.
before:
####KELLY#####
after:
##############

Comment: You may [edit] your question at any time.  Related page: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43762251/2943403

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5024123/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\G` continue metacharacter makes for a messier pattern, but it enables the ability to use `preg_replace()` instead of `preg_replace_callback()`.

Effectively, it looks for the leading three-or-more hashes, then makes single-letter replacements until it reaches the finishing sequence of three-or-more hashes.

This technique also allows hash markers to be "shared" -- I don't actually know if this is something that is desired.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FGgZb))

```
$str = "####KELLY##### and ###ANOTHER###### not ####foo#### but: ###SHARE###MIDDLE###HASHES### ?";
echo $str . "\n";
echo preg_replace('/(?:#{3}|\G(?!^))\K[A-Z](?=[A-Z]*#{3})/', '#', $str);
```

Output:

```
####KELLY##### and ###ANOTHER###### not ####foo#### but: ###SHARE###MIDDLE###HASHES### ?
############## and ################ not ####foo#### but: ############################# ?
```

Breakdown:

```
/               #starting pattern delimiter
(?:             #start non-capturing group
  #{3}          #match three hash symbols
  |             # OR
  \G(?!^)       #continue matching, disallow matching from the start of string
)               #close non-capturing group
\K              #forget any characters matched up to this point
[A-Z]           #match a single letter
(?=             #lookahead (do not consume any characters) for...
    [A-Z]*      #zero or more letters then
    #{3}        #three or more hash symbols
)               #close the lookahead
/               #ending pattern delimiter
```

---

Or you can achieve the same result with `preg_replace_callback()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eIlA0))

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/#{3}\K[A-Z]+(?=#{3})/',
         function($m) {
             return str_repeat('#', strlen($m[0]));
         },
         $str
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with preg_replace_callback function in php.
Thanks CBroe for the tips.

```
preg_replace_callback('/#{3,}([A-Z]+)#{3,}/i', 'replaceLetters', $str);

function replaceLetters($matches) {
    $ret = '';
    for($i=0; $i < strlen($matches[0]); $i++) {
        $ret .= "#"; 
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its education explanation.